# Várias Colunas de Médias Móveis

Tags: r, dplyr

Gostaria de criar várias colunas derivadas da coluna `x`. Essas colunas devem receber as médias móveis de 2, 5... períodos. Tentei fazer a criação com `dplyr::mutate`, porém não deu certo.

```
x <- c(30,35,10,25,15,20,10)

x %>% 
  mutate(spread_3 = rollmean(x, k = 3, fill = NA),
         spread_5 = rollmean(x, k = 5, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o argumento `align = "right"` dentro da função `zoo:rollmean` seja o que é necessário para resolver esse problema.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

x <- data.frame(x = c(30,35,10,25,15,20,10))

x %>% 
  mutate(spread_3 = rollmean(x, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right"),
         spread_5 = rollmean(x, k = 5, fill = NA, align = "right"))
#>    x spread_3 spread_5
#> 1 30       NA       NA
#> 2 35       NA       NA
#> 3 10 25.00000       NA
#> 4 25 23.33333       NA
#> 5 15 16.66667       23
#> 6 20 20.00000       21
#> 7 10 15.00000       16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Quando faço a simulação desse jeito realmente da certo, porém quando rodo no dataframe, ele trás alguns valores NA aonde não deveria.

Comment: abro uma nova pergunta para esse item em questão ou posso tratar diretamente nesse item já aberto?

Comment: Eu abriria uma pergunta nova, seguindo as instruções [desse link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`), para que seja possível reproduzir as tuas condições reais da melhor maneira.

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está com a tag *dplyr*, mas eis uma alternativa usando *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(x)

dt[, `:=`(spread_3 = frollmean(x, 3), spread_5 = frollmean(x, 5))]

> dt
    x spread_3 spread_5
1: 30       NA       NA
2: 35       NA       NA
3: 10 25.00000       NA
4: 25 23.33333       NA
5: 15 16.66667       23
6: 20 20.00000       21
7: 10 15.00000       16
```

Veja a ajuda de `data.table::froll` para detalhes. A vantagem está no caso de precisar criar várias colunas com diferentes janelas de maneira eficiente:

```
dt <- as.data.table(x)

for (n in 2:7) set(dt, j = paste0('spread_', n), value = frollmean(x, n))

> dt
    x spread_2 spread_3 spread_4 spread_5 spread_6 spread_7
1: 30       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
2: 35     32.5       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
3: 10     22.5 25.00000       NA       NA       NA       NA
4: 25     17.5 23.33333    25.00       NA       NA       NA
5: 15     20.0 16.66667    21.25       23       NA       NA
6: 20     17.5 20.00000    17.50       21 22.50000       NA
7: 10     15.0 15.00000    17.50       16 19.16667 20.71429
```