# Como extrair apenas o primeiro valor de uma linha de valores concatenados?

Tags: r

Eu tenho a base de dados abaixo, e gostaria de capturar apenas o primeiro valor de cada linha.

```
a <-  data.frame('Exports' = c("c(182752.414, 179107.7)",
                            "c(200491.435, 195097.2)",
                            "c(217566.642, 211641.4)"))
```

Output esperado:

```
              Exports   
            182752.414
            200491.435
            217556.642
```

Comment: Por favor, Roney, já é um usuário com experiência [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/), pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Comment: Eu votei para fechar a questão. O AP está há quase um mês usando o de maneira intensa e insiste em criar perguntas que não são boas, mesmo sendo advertido disso.

Comment: @Marcus Nunes, boa tarde, como qualificar se uma pergunta é boa ou não? Se estou no site é para buscar resposta que não sei, e de acordo isso replicar a necessidade para pessoas que tiverem dúvidas similares, acho que todos temos dúvidas e se estou fazendo perguntas é porque quero me desenvolver, acho que pessoas com maior conhecimento deveriam colaborar com a causa, se tiver errado em algum ponto por gentileza me sinalizem que com certeza reformularei meu questionamento, estou aqui e sou novo no manuseio do site, faço a ressalva que estou aqui para aprender com muitos outros.

Comment: Eu já te respondi isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494468/v%c3%a1rias-colunas-de-m%c3%a9dias-m%c3%b3veis#comment918714_494471).

Comment: Não entendi, os questionamentos são diferentes.

Comment: Por favor, não usem os comentários para debates. A questão de perguntas aceitáveis [é uma das longas discussões do Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas). Mas a questão de [fornecer exemplo reproduzível que não seja em imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) é um tópico mais do que resolvido.

Comment: Ok @CarlosEduardoLagosta, não quis abrir vertente para discussões mais acaloradas, me desculpe por disponibilizar uma perguntar de maneira não condizente com as diretrizes do site, desde já agradeço pela sinalização e o aprendizado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma expressão regular que captura o conteúdo entre *strings* resolve:

```
a <-  c("c(182752.414, 179107.7)", "c(200491.435, 195097.2)", "c(217566.642, 211641.4)")

as.numeric(sub("^c\\((.*),.*", "\\1", a))
#> [1] 182752.4 200491.4 217566.6
```

Entendendo a expressão: `^` indica o início da *string*; `c\\(` corresponde a "c(", as barras são para indicar que o parênteses é para ser interpretado literalmente, e não como parte da expressão; `(.*)` indica a porção a ser capturada, no caso tudo antes de `,.*` (vírgula seguido de todo o resto). O `\\1` indica para manter o primeiro grupo (a parte delimitada pelo parênteses)

Comment: Obrigado  pela aula @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta!